# Quartz Scheduler stops working when web page is Idle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, quartz-scheduler

When web page is loaded scheduler starts working just fine but when there is no task running in web page or when web page is in idle state the Quartz Scheduler stops working.

Comment: For how long the page was idle? I think due as soon as the worker process stops, quartz will stop working in background. There are multiple ways to resolve this issue but can you provide more details?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have set `SchedulerTimeInterval` for 30 minutes. But Scheduler stops whenever there is no activity on web page.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this follow the below steps:

1. Open IIS server
2. Go to Application Pools
3. Select the Application Pool of your app
4. Click on Advanced Settings on the right panel.
5. Inside the Advance Settings pop up set "Idle Time-out (minutes)" to 0.